# Points of intersection of curves given in parametric equations

Tags: analytic-geometry, curves, parametric

This is the question,

> The points of intersection of the curves whose parametric equations
> are $x=t^2+1, y=2t$ and $x=2s, y=2/s$ is given by:
>
> (a) $(1, –3)$, (b) $(2, 2)$, (c) $(–2, 4)$, (d) $(1, 2)

The answer is $(2,2)$ as per [this website](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/the-point-ofintersection-of-the-curves-whose-parametric-equations-are-x-t21-y-2t-and/)

What I did is I solved the first set of equations and eliminated $t$ and the, equation came out to be, $x^2 = y^2/4 +1$ but the point $(2,2)$ doesn't seem to be satisfying it.

Doesn't it satisfy the equation as it should lie on it also along with the result of the second equation?

Comment: $(2,2)$ is definitely a solution corresponding to $t=1,s=1$. As for your work, you need to show it to us so that we could point to any mistakes.

Comment: Perhaps you don't need $x$  squared? In other words, the equation should be $x=\frac{y^2}{4}+1$?

Comment: Oh, no silly mistake!!!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the parametrics equation $$E_1:\begin{cases}x=t^2+1,\\ y=2t\end{cases},\quad E_2:\begin{cases}x=2s,\\y=2s^{-1}\end{cases}, \quad (t,s)\in {\bf R}\times {\bf R}^*$$
The intersection between the curves $E_1\cap E_2$ can be find solving the non linear system
$$t^2+1=2s,\quad 2t=2s^{-1}$$
Since $2t=2s^{-1}$ then $t=s^{-1}$ and the substitution in $t^2 +1=2s$ give the equivalent equation $(s^{-1})^2+1=2s$ that can be written $\frac{1+s^2}{s^2}=2s$ or $1+s^2=2s^3$.

In order to solve $1+s^2=2s^3$ over ${\bf R}^{*}$ we can write the equation as $2s^3-s^2-1=0$ and the factorization show that $(s-1)(2s^2+s+1)=0$ and it holds if and only if $s-1=0$ or $2s^2+s+1=0$.

The equation $2s^2+s+1=0$ has not solution over ${\bf R}^{*}$ since the $(1)^2-4(2)(1)<0$ and it is a quadratic equation. Therefore, the only solution is $s=1$.

Since $t=s^{-1}$ and $s=1$ we can the only solution $(s,t)=(1,1)$. Therefore, the curves have intersection only in the point $(x,y)=(2,2)$.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT!:

First blue curve eliminating parameter $t$
$$ x=t^2+1, y=2 t,~ y_1= 2 \sqrt{x-1} \tag1 $$

Second purple curve eliminating parameter $s$
$$ x=2 s, y=2/s,~ y_2= 4 /x\tag2 $$

From either of 1) or 2)

$$ y_1=y_2~~; 2 \sqrt{x-1}=4/x$$

$$\to (x_{intxn}=2, y_{intxn}= 2) $$

[image]

Comment: The answer is (2,2)

Comment: But on solving the first set of equation and eliminating `t` I am getting $x = y^2/4 +1$ and (2,1) is not satisfying it.

Comment: In the second line it should be "$t^2+1=2s, t=s^{-1}$". Then, you write $s=t=1$ but then you write $(x,y)=(2,1)$ and it should be a contradiction with the before claim. On other hand, using your way the curves are given by $y=2\sqrt{x-1}, y=4/x$. Of course, since $x=t^2+1$ and $y=2t$, then with $t=y/2$ so $(y/2)^2=x-1$ implies $y^2=4(x-1)$ and similar with $x=2s$ and $y=2/s$ we have $x=2(2/y)=4/y$ implies $y=4/x$.

Comment: Apologies, posted with error.. since edited.